# Power in a circuit why is V constant

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage

In deriving the power of a circuit we can do the following:
$$\text{P}=\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{dQ}{dt}\frac{dw}{dQ}=\text{IV}$$
But this assumes that $V$ (since $w=VQ$) is a constant. Why can we assume this, this is surely not the case for a capacitor where the voltage across it does change with time?
where $Q$ is charge and $w$ is work done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "derivation" you describe is valid at a particular moment in time.

$$\begin{align}\Delta E &= V \Delta Q\\
\frac{dE}{dt} &= V \frac{dQ}{dt} \\&= VI\\
P(t) &=  V(t) I(t)\end{align}$$

I added the dependence on time explicitly.

To address your comments:

$W=QV$ is only true when $V$ is constant; you can't simply take the derivative and then struggle with a reason why $\frac{dV}{dt}$ should be zero. Instead, we say that at a given moment you move charge $\Delta Q$ across a potential of $V$, the work done in that moving is $V\Delta Q$. Then you take the limit of a very short time (during which V doesn't have time to change) and consequently a very small amount of charge; and we call that "charge per time" the current (which at a given instant in time has a finite value).

Comment: If it is only valid at a given time then why do we consider the small change in $Q$ if it is for a given time this to should be 0, why is this not 0?

Comment: We look at $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ - as the time gets shorter, so does the amount of charge. But in the "infinitesimal" limit, the ratio is constant, and we call that the current.

Comment: Alternatively we could say that $\frac{dw}{dt}=Q\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dQ}{dt}$ and what we are saying is that $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$ right? but I still don't get why it has to be 0? even if we are considering it at a particular moment?

Comment: $W=QV$ is only true when $V$ is constant; you can't simply take the derivative and then struggle with a reason why $\frac{dV}{dt}$ should be zero. Instead, if you say that at a given moment you move charge $\Delta Q$ across a potential of $V$, the work done in that moving is $V\Delta Q$. Then you take the limit of a very short time (during which $V$ doesn't have time to change) and consequently a very small amount of charge; and we call that "charge per time" the current (which at a given instant in time has a finite value).

Answer (score 3):

Power is an instantaneous concept.  $P=IV$ gives the instantaneous power at a given instant of time, given $V$ and $I$ at that time.